# Android - ListViews inside tableLayout

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android, android-tablelayout

I'm trying to build and app that shows organized data so I'm thinking that basically a `TableLayout` would be a good idea, just to keep them in rows, so I'm wondering whats the correct way to do it? I have this in my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TableRow>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/hello" >
             </TextView>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="233dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="44dp" >
            </ListView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

then it's just that the `TableLayout` tag and `TableRow` tag displays a warning that says:

```
"This TableLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is possibly useless"
```

so what I understand is that is not picking up the `TableLayout`. how can I fix this? is there another way to do this easly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so what i understand is that is not picking up the tablelayout. how can i fix this? is there another way to do this easly?

Not quite, the renderer **is** taking account of the TableLayout but because the `lint` tool has detected that you have two views when you only need one (A `LinearLayout` and `TableLayout`) it is warning you that **you** should remove one of these layouts as it will boost performance while not effecting the functionality of the page.

I will add, you have a TableLayout with just a single row. TableLayout's are designed to allow their contents to format their columns based upon all of their rows. With a single Row the TableLayout & Row together are acting as a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <ListView>
        <TextView>
```

Since your TableLayout isn't adding any addition layout in that case it becomes obsolete and you will gain a resource boost from removing it and changing the `orientation` of LinearLayout to `horizontal`.

If you're planning to add more `TableRow`'s later, then you should instead remove the `LinearLayout` for the same reason - it will then become the view which is not adding extra information: your table layout will be entirely responsible for the layout so you might as well make it the parent of the layout file (remember to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` attribute to it if you do.)

Comment: wow man, thanks for the info, really instructive, i'll do that and see what comes out, but other thing, if i want to add more rows later say from info in a database, it's better to do it programatically or set the layouts in a xml file?

Comment: If you're pulling out a variable amount of rows, you have no choice but to do it programatically (because you either won't have enough, or you will have redundant rows). If you will always have a set amount (Ie, you have "5 results per page") then defining them in XML is find, you can make the extra's which aren't used as `android:visibility="gone"`.

Answer (score 1):

In general I've seen the stronger warning:

> This LinearLayout layout or its RelativeLayout parent is useless

when this is not the case. For example, this can happen if I've nested a linear layout inside a relative layout. The relative layout positions the linear layout exactly where I want it, the linear layout takes up space. Both are non-useless uses to me.

Answer (score 0):

1) it says *possibly* so avoid drawing conclusions, trust yourself young padawan! But yes, the parent looks useless to me too :)

2) Using Table layout *outside* of your `ListView` wont change the rows' layout in the list, in case this is what you want to achieve.

You might have seen this but the [Developers page offers a really good tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html) that can help you create a good base for your `ListView` (this example uses a `ListActivity`). Then on you can modify the rows' layouts using `TableLayout` ...etc.

Comment: #2 no, it's just to set a text and a list directly in front of it, in the same row. just to make like a scorecard or a contents table kinda layout